# Why can't I update my profile? "temporary error updating your profile"

Tags: bug, profile-page, editing-help, accounts

I made numerous much-needed edits to my profile.  But now it won't save!

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   temporary error updating your profile -- please try again!

I have tried dozens of times over about 12 hours, even undoing some of my changes (in case specific changes cause the problem).

Methinks Stack Overflow failing to specify the actual—underlying—error is bad error handling.

---

Related questions mention account merging as a possible solution.

How do I do this?

Comment: Not done any account merges recently? Do you also have a Stack Overflow for Teams profile / are you in a Stack Overflow for Teams team.

Comment: @rene:  I have never had anything to do with teams.   But I do recall when I signed up eight years ago I used OpenID.  But now I use Google.

Comment: Hi! Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @AdamLear:  The method to edit a profile looks all different.  Was it the case where there was only one profile site-wide (throughout all StackExchange sites)?  I'm not seeing an obvious "edit my profile" option now.  Only a way to copy from one to another.

Comment: @wallyk There should be a way to either save your profile to all sites or on the one you're on specifically. Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?